# Uploading an invoice for an Amazon order in the most straightforward way

Tags: .net, amazon-selling-partner-api

my company has recently started selling on Amazon.de, we are using a 3rd party middleware for integration. It only supports retrieving orders from Amazon and notifying shipment/cancellation.

I was tasked with implementing uploading invoices directly to Amazon for each order. (we won't be using Amazon VAT calculation service, we generate our own invoices and want to upload them) For this I need to integrate with Amazon directly (from .NET C#). I've been researching how to do it for the past two days, and the more I do it the more confused I am.

I have some questions I would like to clarify:

I was given a link to this:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api/docs/option-3-upload-invoices-through-sp-api-or-seller-central
There is a code sample here, but it's not that useful, as it seems to be making use of some other code that is not mentioned - SubmitFeedRequest, getMarketplaceWebServiceClient() - where are these from? Is this some dll, some Nuget that Amazon is providing?

Also, what's the difference between SP-API and MWS API? As far as I understand, these are two separate API's, although some guides seem to conflate them. Which one would be better to use? So far we've worked under the assumption that we will be using SP-API, and we went through the auth setup with my manager (they won't give me access to seller central). So I have the following information: User ARN, Role ARN, Application ID, SP-API Token. If I decide to go with MWS, will I we have to do the whole setup again?

I've also found this guide:
https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api-blog/docs/automate-your-sp-api-calls-using-the-c-sdk
It contains instructions to... generate an SDK by myself? Is this what I'm supposed to do? Isn't there a simpler way?

Answer (score -2):

Unfortunately, you do have to generate the C# SDK on your own. Amazon recently released a blog on how to do this, https://developer-docs.amazon.com/sp-api-blog/docs/automate-your-sp-api-calls-using-the-c-sdk. They have more detailed documentation for how to do it with Java.

Amazon MWS is being deprecated and all new development must be done using the SP API (So at least you won't have to get your credentials again).

I found some repos on github of pregenerated C# sdks, maybe they'll work for you. Here are 2 that were helpful for me:

https://github.com/jadanah/amazon-selling-partner-api-csharp-samples
https://github.com/abuzuhri/Amazon-SP-API-CSharp

Comment: You did not completely answer the post.